# how to retry Http post requests with timeout

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am working on an API implementation where I would like to have a time limit for getting a response from a microservice and if the response is not received within the time limit then retry again for some more time(say 3 times)

```
import requests

url = 'http://example.com:8000/demo'
payload = {'data1': 1, 'data2': 2}
try:
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
except:
    return   # if the requests.post does not give response in a specific time-limit then I would like to retry request 3 times
```

Is there an inbuilt function in python where I can have a `timeout` and the `retry the request for # times`?

Comment: Requests can handle the retries for you using urllib3 retry objects. I don't have the docs to hand but I have done this in the past..

Answer (score 1):

Ah you are doing very fine on the algorithm part.

Pretty sure you can build the loop yourself. I like to use `range()` in your case.

On the timeout part, requests has indeed your back :

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts